# Use tslint-eslint-rules with Gulp.js

Tags: npm, gulp, eslint, tslint

Objective: Use TSLint to lint any TS files in the project done using VS 2015

I set up a gulp task as follows (from [Setup TSLint in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179461/setup-tslint-in-visual-studio-2015)):

```
//The actual task to run
gulp.task("TSLint:All", function () {
    return gulp.src(TYPE_SCRIPT_FILES)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(tslint())
        .pipe(tslint.report(
            "verbose", {
                emitError: false,
                reportLimit: 50
            }));
});
```

Things were working fine. Now I want to use the tslint-eslint-rules rules for linting.

I do the following

1. Install the eslint-eslint-rules package as shown on https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules

---

2. Create file called tslint.json as shown below

---

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": "node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules",
  "rules": {
    "no-constant-condition": true
  }
}
```

---

3. Change my Gulp task as follows

---

```
gulp.task("TSLint:All", function () {
    return gulp.src(TYPE_SCRIPT_FILES)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(tslint({
            configuration: "tslint.json"
        }
        ))
        .pipe(tslint.report(
            "verbose", {
                emitError: false,
                reportLimit: 50
            }));
});
```

I start getting the following error (I believe for every error flagged by Linter):
Plumber found unhandled error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token

How can I correct this ?

Comment: Try to re-save your tslint.json with encoding Western European (ISO) - Codepage 28591. This worked for me.